# Run Unix "Chmod" command on a file structure within a C# Winform Application

Tags: c#, linux, winforms

### Question

Is it possible to run a Unix Chmod command on a folder recursively from a winform?

### Background

I have an application that moves folders from one area to another within a linux file system. However at the moment it is failing when the owner of the file doesn't match the username of the person trying to move the folder.

### Chmod Command

```
chmod -r user: folder
```

User   = The user that is trying to access the folder
folder = the folder the user is trying to access

### My solution

When my application goes to do the transfer. Run a command to ensure that the permissions of the folder are set to the match the username of the person trying to do the transfer.

### Note

I know a lot of you will say it is surely better to sort the permissions out then go about it this way. You are correct, this is just a quick fix until I get to the bottom of the permission issue.

Comment: Little confused as you've tagged the question as c#?

Comment: My application is written in c# and that is the language i plan on implementing the cmd. The win form is written in c#.